# Python Seaborn and Pandas Data Presentatation in Graphical Form

Tags: python, seaborn

I was trying ML in python. During the process I had to come across `seaborn.pairplot` or other plot function and `pandas.plot` functions. To be simple I'm putting the scope of this question within `seaborn` only as the same solution is likely to work for pandas also.

I was trying the very basic codes presented in seaborn website.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip")
g.ax.axline(xy1=(10, 2), slope=.2, color="b", dashes=(5, 2))
```

The datasets have been cloned from seaborn Github repository. Still the moment the execution comes to `sns.*plot()` functions it gives a `'NoneType' object is not callable Error`.

The seaborn dataset from Git repository has quite a few csv datesets.A bove was about `tips.csv`. `sns.load_dataset("tips")` can load the dataset `tips.csv` from current directory. Whereas for another dataset `penguins` residing in the same directory `sns.load_dataset("penguins")` fails!

After `os` is imported by `import os` within `penguins.py`, `print(os.getcwd())` gives a different result even though both `penguins.csv` and `tips.csv` are in the same folder and also `penguins.py` and `tips.py` are in the same folder but different from dataset folder as blow.

```
'D:\Protege\Documents\Seaborn\~.csv' #where all datasets are 
'D:\Protege\Documents\Seaborn\process\~.py' #where all ~.py files are
```

For tips `os.getcwd` rightly gives the first directory. Whereas in `penguins.py` the same function gives the second result.

If I put `sns.load_dataset('D:\Protege\Documents\Seaborn\Penguins.csv')` it says penguins is not one of the datasets.

Let's discuss for tips and `'NoneType' object is not callable Error` first.

Comment: `sns.load_dataset(...)` is only meant to read seaborn's standard example datasets, which are stored at seaborn's github.  To load another `.csv` file, you need `pd.read_csv(....)` (or `pd.read_html(...)`,  `pd.read_excel(...)`, `pd.read_pickle(....)`, `pd.read_json(...)`). Often, you need to provide more parameters, as such files can be stored in many different ways. See a.o. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html

Comment: About `g.ax.axline(...)` not working, this might be due to using an older seaborn version.  Something like `for ax in g.axes.flatten(): ax.axline(...)` might work. Note that `axline` is a rather new function, so you'll need a recent matplotlib version.  You might also want to take a look at seaborn's discussion about [figure-level vs axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions). `g.ax` only has a valid version in the latest seaborn version, and only in case you are using a figure-level function with exactly one subplot.

Comment: @JohanC you mean 'sns.load_dataset() ' will work with loading from GitHub only not from the cloned copy of the GitHub repository on my device. WIll 'sns.~plot ()' function be working with data read using 'pd.read_~()'? #~ csv etc. By the i use Visual Studio 2019 and Python version 3.10.

Comment: Well, the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html) and the [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/bfbd6ad5b9717db42e302177d867b4a273df162b/seaborn/utils.py#L532) explain `sns.load_dataset(name)` will only load from `({name}.csv on https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data).`  This helps to easily create reproducible tutorial examples, reproducible bug reports and reproducible stackoverflow questions and answers.

Comment: The seaborn functions work with several types of data.  They are primarily meant to work with pandas dataframes, but also work with python lists, 1D or 2D numpy arrays and even dictionaries that mimic dataframes. `sns.load_dataset` internally use `pd.load_csv`, but also changes some columns to `pd.Categorical` to obtain reproducible ordering.

Comment: @richardec thanks for beautification of my original post.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for your additional comments and resource links.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from compatibility of different python packages to python version 3.10. Also my platform visual studio 2019 still does not fully support python 3.10 itself. I was trying to get a list of which python graphical presentation packages are compatible with python 3.10. Could not progress much.

Comment: Well, did you try to use `tips = pd.read_csv()`? `sns.load_dataset()` is really only meant to read from github.   Did you try `tips.info()`, `print(tips.describe()))` and/or `print(tips.head())` to check that the dataframe was well read?

Comment: @JohanC, thanks for your comments again. Just as I thought the problem is coming from version compatibility. I tried to execute a `seaborn.*plot` function in `google colab` platform. It works. I still though don't know which versions of `python` and ` python packages` colab is using. Microsoft has to fix the problem on their visual studio.